# Facing issues because of Database Backup Activity

Tags: data-warehouse, database-backups, greenplum

We're having some issues while having the backup of database.
The user used for the same has the most priority on the database server. Because of that the loading of other tables having lower priority user are getting stuck at T state.

Is there any way how we can solve the issue.

In simple words:
Suppose we're having the daily backup of some of the schemas available in database and there are 2-3 database users i.e. A, B, C.
The user An is the super most user, so whenever we run any query with user A, database gives more preference to the queries hit by user A. User A used to take the backup.
At the same time we have the loading of daily tables i.e. Stg and Fact tables with user B which is having low priority than user A.

Comment: "*so whenever we run any query with user A, database gives more preference to the queries hit by user A*" this is most definitely not true for Postgres. Postgres has no concept of "priorities" for users or queries

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to backup?
gpcrondump? gpbackup?

Backups are supposed to be non-blocking for the most part --

During backups:

The gpcrondump utility locks the pg_class system table and the tables that are backed up. Locking the pg_class table with an EXCLUSIVE lock ensures that no tables are added, deleted, or altered until gpcrondump locks tables that are to be backed up with ACCESS SHARE locks.

The gpbackup backup process acquires an ACCESS SHARE lock on each table that is backed up.

I would recommend going with the latter, as it is generally faster, and uses non EXCLUSIVE locks. But if something else is going to be modifying DDL or table definitions during your backup job -- that's going to be an issue as the EXCLUSIVE lock request for these actions will conflict and need to wait. However, they should resume once the job is completed.